# How do you find the point touching the tangent line on a unit circle?

Tags: trigonometry, circles, tangent-line

For a unit circle and a normalised vector representing the tangent (could be pointing in either direction), of which, would be touching the circle's perimeter, how do you find the point on the circle for it ?

[image]

Comment: what is a vector representing the tangent? The correct way to do this is to define the tangent space at the point on your circle. The arrow you drew is not a tangent vector.

Comment: Its just a direction with a magnitude of 1, i didn't draw it on the circle, but the idea is, since i have a normalised vector i want to use it as the tangent in order to find the point on the circle that vector would be touching. The problem that springs to my mind currently is theres two points for any given vector as a tangent which is kinda confusing me on how you find the point for a tangent line.

Answer (score 0):

For spheres the *normal* pointing outwards in a point $p$ on the boundary is given by the vector $p$. The tangent vectors are  orthogonal to the normal.

So in your case, finding the point where, given a tangent direction, the tangent can meet the circle is just a matter of rotating the direction by 90 degrees. However the question and this solution don’t specify a unique such point, but rather two antipodal points. But this can be easily modified to result in a unique solution, at least for 2d spheres: We fix a vector field of tangent directions, say counterclockwise. Then rotating the tangent directions by 90 degrees in clockwise direction will give you normals pointing outwards, which are unique and give you the corresponding touching point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just wondering what is the best way to evaluate whether the tangent direction suggests clockwise or counter clockwise on a circle at some tangent point?

Comment: No I mean **you** have to decide whether you want to have tangent vectors oriented clockwise or counterclockwise around the circle. As you have noticed correctly, a tangent can have two different directions in the same point. Moreover there are precisely two parallel tangent lines to the circle. So unless **you** fix a direction of these tangent lines to distinguish them, the problem is ill-posed...